# Yorkshire encephalitis medications and Turmeric

Tags: dogs, medicines

I have a 6 y.o. Yorkshire and he was diagnosed with Yorkshire encephalitis ~8 months ago.

I read very good things about Turmeric and sea weeds for encephalitis, and I wonder if it can be mixed with his current medications (the vets around here don't know much about alternative medicines).

The current medications are:

- Phenobarbitone
- Cellcept
- Potassium Bromide (KBR)
- Prednisolone
- Keppra
- Omeprazole

Please mention your background on your answers :)